# Is google compute engine capable or running big server side programs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-contacts-api

1. Do we need to code specially for utilizing all the cores of an instance of the virtual machine in google compute engine ? ( threading )
2. If I add a new instance with an existing instance in which an app is running, does the system dynamically scale up its entire configuration or the second instance runs independent from the first?

   - If independent: Is there a way of making two instance communicate with each other?
3. Is read and write from multiple instance possible in a single persistence disk?
4. Is there a maximum limit for the network traffic that can be handled by an instance?

5) What is the worst case delay in the communication between two instances running at different regions?

Comment: AFAIK, it can as you can choose their servers with a predefined configuration or an option to *create Custom Machine Types optimized for your specific needs.* There are different documents that can help you e.g. [Tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials), [How-to Guides](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/how-to), [APIs and Reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/apis) to be familiar on what Google Compute Engine is capable of.

Comment: You can also try asking [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine) and visiting [Google Cloud Platform Blog](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/). Hope this helps.

Comment: I came here after searching their entire documentation page, contacted their sales team, searched the entire google engine and couldn't find an apt answer for these questions. I want a server with 1TB RAM and the max RAM for an instance is 128 GB, so i was planning to make many instance of the same type for load balancing. But such constraints held me back from this. I want scientifically reliable and engineering apt answers. I prefer Binary's Yes or No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes.  Compute engine is capable of running "big" server side programs.

Now reading the text below the title I would recommend looking at AppEngine.  It scales to load.  And you can use Memcache or Datastore to store and share data quickly among all instances, even across regions.

Comment: Should I gain advantage while using library's like openCL while doing  parallel computing in different cores which are spread across different instances ?

Comment: Nope the beauty of AppEngine is that you can scale without thinking about threading--as long as each process can run a chunk of work independently.  You can put millions of tasks into TaskQueue and AppEngine will spawn as many resources needed (up to a potential maximum you specify) to tackle the load. If you need more control over how parallel processing works (e.g. if you need a map-reduce type of workload) you might considering using "Bigtable." And lastly if you have just massive data and you need to scan it quickly then "BigQuery" is your tool. Architecture / tool depends on your problem.

Comment: Can you precisely explain what you meant by ( each process ) and ( Task Queue ). I have  source code of a MMORTS which was written in c and cpp and was compiled into a single .exe with some supporting files. How can i squeeze maximum performance out of google compute engines ? .

Comment: I'm sorry but what you really need is hours of consulting with a technical architect.  Your problem isn't clear and besides that it's very hard to optimize someone else's code, especially something designed as a monolithic executable.  In general the road to speed is parallel-ization.  And to do that you need to break the program into separately executable components.  Only then will cloud platforms help.